# why services are not shown in zipkin?

Tags: spring-cloud, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

- I use Spring boot: **1.5.16**
- Spring cloud: **Edgware.RELEASE**
- Java: **1.8**

My Sampler looks like that:

```
 @Bean
    public Sampler sampler(){
        return new AlwaysSampler();
 }
```

In Eureka everything seems well:
[image]

But my problem is that in Zipkin I can't see services at all.
[image]

I found only debug logs, I have no errors:

```
2018-09-18 05:15:53.831 DEBUG [reservation-client,,,] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : Received a request to uri [/reservations] that should not be sampled [false]
2018-09-18 05:15:53.832 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,950c6b586ebb2d56,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : No parent span present - creating a new span
2018-09-18 05:15:53.832 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,950c6b586ebb2d56,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.s.i.web.TraceHandlerInterceptor    : Handling span [Trace: 950c6b586ebb2d56, Span: 950c6b586ebb2d56, Parent: null, exportable:true]
2018-09-18 05:15:53.832 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,950c6b586ebb2d56,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.s.i.web.TraceHandlerInterceptor    : Adding a method tag with value [writeReservation] to a span [Trace: 950c6b586ebb2d56, Span: 950c6b586ebb2d56, Parent: null, exportable:true]
2018-09-18 05:15:53.832 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,950c6b586ebb2d56,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.s.i.web.TraceHandlerInterceptor    : Adding a class tag with value [ReservationApiGatewayRestController] to a span [Trace: 950c6b586ebb2d56, Span: 950c6b586ebb2d56, Parent: null, exportable:true]
2018-09-18 05:15:53.833  INFO [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,950c6b586ebb2d56,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] .e.r.ReservationApiGatewayRestController : VQ start sending!!!
2018-09-18 05:15:53.833 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,950c6b586ebb2d56,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.s.i.m.TraceChannelInterceptor      : Processing message before sending it to the channel
2018-09-18 05:15:53.833 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,950c6b586ebb2d56,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.s.i.m.TraceChannelInterceptor      : Parent span is [Trace: 950c6b586ebb2d56, Span: 950c6b586ebb2d56, Parent: null, exportable:true]
2018-09-18 05:15:53.833 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,950c6b586ebb2d56,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.s.i.m.TraceChannelInterceptor      : Name of the span will be [message:output]
2018-09-18 05:15:53.833 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,74b3c2b9366ff711,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.s.i.m.TraceChannelInterceptor      : Marking span with client send
2018-09-18 05:15:53.833 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,74b3c2b9366ff711,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.s.i.m.TraceChannelInterceptor      : Completed sending and current span is [Trace: 950c6b586ebb2d56, Span: 74b3c2b9366ff711, Parent: 950c6b586ebb2d56, exportable:true]
2018-09-18 05:15:53.833 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,74b3c2b9366ff711,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.s.i.m.TraceChannelInterceptor      : Marking span with client received
2018-09-18 05:15:53.833 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,74b3c2b9366ff711,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.s.i.m.TraceChannelInterceptor      : Closing messaging span [Trace: 950c6b586ebb2d56, Span: 74b3c2b9366ff711, Parent: 950c6b586ebb2d56, exportable:true]
2018-09-18 05:15:53.833 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,74b3c2b9366ff711,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.s.zipkin2.DefaultEndpointLocator   : Span will contain serviceName [reservation-client]
2018-09-18 05:15:53.834 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,950c6b586ebb2d56,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.s.i.m.TraceChannelInterceptor      : Messaging span [Trace: 950c6b586ebb2d56, Span: 74b3c2b9366ff711, Parent: 950c6b586ebb2d56, exportable:true] successfully closed
2018-09-18 05:15:53.834 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,950c6b586ebb2d56,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : Closing the span [Trace: 950c6b586ebb2d56, Span: 950c6b586ebb2d56, Parent: null, exportable:true] since the response was successful
2018-09-18 05:15:53.834 DEBUG [reservation-client,950c6b586ebb2d56,950c6b586ebb2d56,true] 3759 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.c.s.zipkin2.DefaultEndpointLocator   : Span will contain serviceName
```

Question is simple. Why can't I see anything in Zipkin?
This samples are written by [Josh Long.](https://github.com/joshlong/bootiful-microservices)

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration file and make sure the baseUrl is given properly here

```
    spring.zipkin.baseUrl
```